# gc overhead in bufferedreader or inputstreamreader

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
{
    Connection connection;
    ZipFile zipFile = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        zipFile = new ZipFile(fileUpload);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        ZipEntry entry;
        String line = "";
        DBBridge dbBridge = new DBBridge();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            entry = entries.nextElement();
            boolean firstLineSkipped = false;
            boolean insertStockFlag = false;
            inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] stockData = line.split(",");
                if (firstLineSkipped && !insertStockFlag){ 
                    dbBridge.insertStockSP(connection, stockData[0], stockData[11], stockData[12], stockData[13]);
                    insertStockFlag = true;
                }
                if(firstLineSkipped && insertStockFlag) {
                    dbBridge.insertStockDailyInfo(connection, stockData[0], stockData[1], stockData[2], stockData[3], stockData[4], stockData[5], stockData[6], stockData[7], stockData[8], stockData[9], stockData[10], stockData[14]);
                }
                firstLineSkipped = true;
            }
            reader.close();
            reader = null;
            bufferedReader.close();
            bufferedReader = null;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (FileLockInterruptionException e) {
        return ERROR;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ERROR;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return ERROR;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return ERROR;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ERROR;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (zipFile != null){
                zipFile.close();
                zipFile = null;
            }
            if (inputStream != null){
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream = null;
            }
            if (bufferedReader != null){
                bufferedReader.close();
                bufferedReader = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* e.printStackTrace(); */
        }
    }
}
```

This is my method to import some csv file in a zip file, but i face the problem of gc overhead limit exceeded. Is the problem caused by bufferedreader of inputstreamreader? What can i do? What causes this error?

Edit: This is my `insertStockSP` in `DBBridge`

```
    public void insertStockSP(Connection connection,String symbolName, String Code, String latinName, String persianName) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{call insertStock(?,?,?,?)}");
    proc.setString(1, symbolName);
    proc.setString(2, Code);
    proc.setString(3, latinName);
    proc.setString(4, persianName);
    proc.execute();
}
```

i don't think the problem is this. `insertStockDailyInfo` is like that.

```
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:64)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:108)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.normalize(Win32FileSystem.java:122)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.normalize(Win32FileSystem.java:189)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:367)
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.file(FileDirContext.java:765)
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.doGetAttributes(FileDirContext.java:398)
at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.getAttributes(BaseDirContext.java:1137)
at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.getAttributes(BaseDirContext.java:1090)
at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.getAttributes(ProxyDirContext.java:882)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.modified(WebappClassLoader.java:1026)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:420)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:394)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:180)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3135)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2892)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.error(CommonsLogger.java:38)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:903)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

this is stack trace, i have to say i work with Struts 2.

Comment: No, the problem is caused by *your code*. Get into the habit of looking there first. What for example do `dbBridge.insertStockSP()` and ` dbBridge.insertStockDailyInfo()` do? Anything that consumes memory?

Comment: You have a resource leak in `insertStockSP()`. You're never closing the `CallableStatement`. As predicted. No doubt you have another one in `insertStockDailyInfo()`. Two leaks per line of input.

Comment: Ow, i would try it, if that's the problem, shame on me! Thank you @EJP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several thoughts about potential ineficiencies/problems:

1) Why don't you use ZipInputStream instead of ZipFile since you don't need to have random access to inner entries in the middle of your file
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/UnzipusingtheZipInputStream.htm

2) I would advise you to check file extention to make sure you deal with text file containing relatively short lines. It could happen that reading line by line from binary file may cause loading into memory insanely long strings with garbage inside.

3) You could have memory leak in methods of `dbBridge`.

Comment: If i understood right, it is unzipping the file, but that is not what i mean. I want to read almost 2000 .CSV file which is as you know fully text.
I guess problem is with `new` keyword but i couldn't find any replace for that in constructing readers. I tested the code with increased heap size and it got 2GB of my RAM and again failed.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with new keyword. You don't seem to store all these files in memory (unless `dbBridge` does it). Can you show your error stack trace?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in DBBridge, i should've closed 'CallableStatement' after execution. Thanks for your help.